# Pick columns to display in table at run time in .Net MVC 5 & Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, anonymous

I am building an application that allows the user to pick the columns they want to display in a table, as well as some basic filtering.  In the past web forms world I have built sql strings and used the gridview with auto generate columns.

This seems much more difficult in the strongly typed world of MVC and Entity Framework.

What I am looking for is an article, how-to, example, or some direction on this.  I have been looking around and only found bits an pieces.  It seems like this would be a common task, but there is not much out there.  I have looked into ExpandoObject, DynamicSQL, EQSL, etc., these maybe the answer, but looking for guidance, I know others have done this.

Looking for an efficient and not too difficult to implement solution, there are less then 75 columns to choose from.

Looking for;

1. Best way to pull the data, would like to only have the selected columns.
2. Best way display build the table, must have only the selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework isn't really good for something like this. While it does have support for returning only a subset of fields (for example, if you use `Select` in your query it will only pull the columns that are utilized), it doesn't really have a way to achieve something similar in a dynamic way. However, you can very much still drop down to straight SQL queries if you need to, which is probably the best way to handle this situation:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Foo>(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM dbo.Foos", columns));
```

Where `columns` would be a string representing the columns to be selected (warning: could result in SQL injection. You'll need to sanitize `columns` properly before using this). By using the generic version of this method, you'll actually get back a enumerable (`DbRawSqlQuery<T>` actually) of proper instances of the type (`Foo` in this case), largely the same as what you would have gotten from using the Entity Framework methods.

**EDIT**

My mistake. I haven't had a need to do this myself, so I missed that this doesn't really help you much. You can select a subset of columns in this way, but you must have a type to bind to that *only* includes that subset of properties. In other words, given:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Something1 { get; set; }

    ...

    public string Something 10 { get; set; }
}

public class PartialFoo
{
    public string Something2 { get; set; }

    public string Something5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<PartialFoo>("SELECT Something2, Something5 FROM dbo.Foos");
```

Anything else, would raise an exception. Which obviously doesn't help much, since you've still pretty much have to know in advance what columns are selected. Although, if you have a preset number of combinations, it's possible that you could create a handful of DTOs that would allow you to get the info you needed.

Otherwise, trying to force this into working dynamically seems to be a headache (see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-4-1-SqlQuery).